# Display map from Geoserver in OSMDroid

Tags: android, openlayers, osmdroid, geoserver, tms

I've cached tiles in Geoserver and I need display map in my android application over OSMDroid. I've tried it with my web application with OpenLayers and works fine like this:

```
 var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
            })
        })
```

So now I need display it in Android. I've created class for custom tile source:

```
public class GeoserverTileSource extends OnlineTileSourceBase {

public static String[] TILE_URL = {"http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png"};

public GeoserverTileSource(String aName, int aZoomMinLevel, int aZoomMaxLevel, int aTileSizePixels, String aImageFilenameEnding, String[] aBaseUrl) {
    super(aName, aZoomMinLevel, aZoomMaxLevel, aTileSizePixels, aImageFilenameEnding, aBaseUrl);
}

@Override
public String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile) {
    return TILE_URL[0] + "/" + aTile.getZoomLevel() + "/" + aTile.getX() + "/" + aTile.getY();
}
```

}

and here is my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    //important! set your user agent to prevent getting banned from the osm servers
    Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    GeoserverTileSource source = new GeoserverTileSource("geoserver", 10, 18, 256, ".png", GeoserverTileSource.TILE_URL);

    map.setTileSource(source);
    //map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
}


public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Configuration.getInstance().load(this, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
}
```

}

Geoserver log print this:

```
2017-03-04 14:29:20,451 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - null http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png/18/642/281
2017-03-04 14:29:20,460 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - null http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png/18/639/281
2017-03-04 14:29:20,460 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - null http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png/18/640/280
2017-03-04 14:29:20,472 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - null http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png/18/637/281
2017-03-04 14:29:20,473 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - null http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png/18/638/281
2017-03-04 14:29:20,480 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - null http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png/18/639/280
2017-03-04 14:29:20,480 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - null http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png/18/641/279
```

after geoserver turn up geoserver debugging log:
http://pastebin.com/wTw5ASDC

At first I've tried Mapnik tile source and it works ... but my not :/ Can you tell me what I do wrong? Thanks

EDIT:
I've editted my funcition getTileURLString to this and still not works:

```
@Override
public String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile) {
    return TILE_URL[0] + "/" + aTile.getZoomLevel() + "/" + aTile.getX() + "/" + aTile.getY() + ".png";
}
```

so I tried url from log file in brwser and I got this:
[image]

and when I tried url with ".png" on the end I got this:
[image]

android studio terminal print this:

```
W/OsmDroid: Problem downloading MapTile: /10/651/444 HTTP response: 
W/OsmDroid: Problem downloading MapTile: /10/649/444 HTTP response: 
W/OsmDroid: Problem downloading MapTile: /10/648/445 HTTP response: 
W/OsmDroid: Problem downloading MapTile: /10/650/445 HTTP response: 
W/OsmDroid: Problem downloading MapTile: /10/649/445 HTTP response:
```

Is possible the osmdroid call url with wrong parameters? Becouse as you can see on picture, structure names are little different, and they contains underscore.
[image]

Comment: turn the geoserver logging level up to developer and try again

Comment: ok I turn up it, and I have new log ... so I editted question.

Comment: And luck finding a solution??? I'm trying to achieve something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoServer is saying it doesn't know how to handle a request like:

```
http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png/11/9/3
```

This is because you haven't specified an image format, so a URL like this should work:

```
http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png/11/9/3.png
```

Comment: Still not works, I update my question again, and add screens what geoserver return when I call this urls.